# How to manage Google Colab's tendency for timing out

Tags: google-colaboratory

I need to run a model on Colab (one-off). Most recently it timed out after running for about 6 hours. I had the tab open in front of me and was working on another screen. When I looked again (last viewed only a few minutes before), the runtime had timed out. I'm not sure if a  captcha had appeared that I missed. During the 6 hours before, the captcha had only appeared once.

I need to use Google Colab rather than an alternative. I could try Colab Pro/Pay As You Go but I'm not sure this would solve the time out issue - I have no need to close the tab but I also can't look continuously at the screen for a captcha for 6 hours. I know that Colab Pro + allows background execution but I can't pay for this. Any suggestions welcome! Even something like a sound notification when the captcha pops up would help.